# What is causing my infinite loop?

Tags: java, loops

I can't seem to figure out what I did wrong with my code to create an infinite loop. I would really appreciate it if someone could help explain this to me.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class LoopMath1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner inputScanner;
        inputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        //gets a number from a user and parses the string as an int
        System.out.println("Please give me a positive number");
        String userNum;
        userNum = inputScanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Your number is " + userNum + ".");
        int number = Integer.parseInt(userNum);

        printX(number);  //function call

        //prints 2 to the x power
        System.out.print("2^" + number + "=");
        int j = 1;
        int twoToThe = 2;
        while (j < number) {
            twoToThe *= 2;
            j++;
        }
        System.out.print(twoToThe);

        //determines if the user number is prime
        int i = 0;
        for (i = 1; 1 < number; i++) {
            int nPrime = number;
            if (nPrime == 0) {
                System.out.println(number + " is not prime.");
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.println(number + " is prime.");
            }

        }
    }

    //this is a function to print a certain amount of Xs, depending          on the user input
    public static void printX(int nTimes) {
        final int WIDTH = nTimes;
        while (nTimes < WIDTH) {
            System.out.print("x");
            nTimes += 1;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tagging this with java will be useful

Comment: Also lookup the "halting problem". I think Java has a solution in the standard api

Comment: which loop is inifinite.... did you check the number input by the user??

Comment: I'm sorry you are receiving so many down votes without people explaining their down votes. (That's really bad form, people!) I assume they are down voting because your question can be much more concise -- "why does this produce an infinite loop?" (followed by reduced code). As is, your question comes across as "Please help me finish my homework!" See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @DawsonToth [Nah, I lost my keys.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215379/should-drive-by-downvoting-be-more-effectively-caught/215397#215397)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
    for (i=1; 1 < number; i++) {
```

by

```
    for (i=1; i < number; i++) {
```

Your incrementor initialized in the first part of your for loop must be tested in the second part preferably and incremented in the third one.

Answer (score 3):

`for (i=1; 1 < number; i++)` has a typo. `1` should be `i` as in `for (i=1; i < number; i++)`

Comment: nTimes < WIDTH will also always be false.
    final int WIDTH = nTimes;
    while (nTimes < WIDTH) {

Comment: Agreed this is also a problem with the program.